# Show load bar for slide show, preload images, then show slide show

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple slideshow, how do I go about showing some sort of load rectangle before the slideshow starts?  Right now on a slow connection the slide show is kinda funky until the first image fully loads.

Comment: Can you provide an example? What do you mean with funky?

Comment: @myself. I like it funky </offtopic>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a throbber as a background.

```
#slideshow {
    background: url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Alternatively, you could...

```
var images = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg'],
    imagesLoaded = 0,
    totalImages = images.length;

$.each(images, function(i, image) {

   var img = new Image();

   img.onload = function() {
       imagesLoaded++;
       if (imagesLoaded == totalImages) {
           // All images done
       }
   };

   img.src = image;

});
```